# How to get servicePrincipal info having just the token?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Using the `/me` endpoint doesn't work service principal. How can I get the same information for service principal using just the token? I would like to avoid calling `/users/id` because I don't have the ID or any other information

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly do you need? I assume that you call Graph API from background services or daemons. Do you have at least application id?

Comment: @user2250152 I don't have application ID. I am calling Graph API from an application. I have a bearer token that is passed onto my application. The bearer token is generated for a servicePrincipal in an outside process. So the only information I have is the token. I want to get info similar to what would https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me return. Except that it doesn't work for a servicePrincipal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use some token decoder to get `appId` from metadata.

Access token from Graph API is JWT.

Example for C#

NuGet package `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` has the class `JwtSecurityTokenHandler` which can be used for decoding access token.

```
var token = "eyJ0eXAiOiJK...";
var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var jwtSecurityToken = handler.ReadJwtToken(token);
var appIdClaim = jwtSecurityToken.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "appid");
string appId = null;
if (appIdClaim != null)
{
    appId = appIdClaim.Value;
}
else
{
    appId = jwtSecurityToken.Payload["appid"] as string;
}
```

Now use `/servicePrincipals` endpoint to get details about [servicePrincipal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/serviceprincipal?view=graph-rest-1.0)

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals(appId='{appId}')
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals?$filter=appId eq '{appId}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you can try to get a list of service principals:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals
```

The response contains the name and Id's of the service principals which can be used.

You can use different filers to get them with name aslo:

[image]

For more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-3-use-filter-and-top-to-get-one-service-principal-with-a-display-name-that-starts-with-a-including-a-count-of-returned-objects

Hope this helps.